# In UCM ,how to verify whether any check in happened in a particular folder?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

We are having a build script which will be running every day morning at 5 AM.

It will blindly run even if no changes made. Now we would like to add this intelligence to our script.

I need to verify in a particular folder whether any checkin has happened previous day. If so trigger the build and send notification else send notification mail saying no changes done previous day and you can use earlier day build itself.

Assume , My folder is "Myproj/Coding". There are many other folders like "MyProj/Documentation" ,"MyProj/Deployment". I need to check only in the coding folder for changes made at previous day.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a cleartool find in order to list any *new* version created since yesterday (see [IBM search examples](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425))

```
cleartool find Myproj/Coding -version "{created_since(date1)}" -print
```